# Add a folder into a workspace by tasks in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Is there a way to add a folder into a workspace by tasks?

Is it possible to add and remove (or hide) folders in a workspace on selecting options from input in *tasks.json*?

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "selectProject",
            "type": "pickString",
            "description": "Some decription",
            "options":
            [
               "PROJECT1",
               "PROJECT2"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "add into workspace",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "command-to-add-folder-into-workspace", // what do I need to put here?
            "args": [
                "${input:selectProject}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution using `code --add folder` in tasks.

File `.code-workspace`

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "name": "wp",
            "path": "../wp" // folder has .code-workspace file
        }
    ],
    "settings": { /*...*/ },
    "tasks": {
        "inputs":[
                {
                    "id": "selectProject",
                    "type": "pickString",
                    "description": "select project",
                    "options":
                    [
                        "PROJECT1",
                           "PROJECT2"
                    ]
                }
        ],
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "Add project",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "code", // usind command code --add folder
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
                },
                "args": [
                    "--add",
                    "../${input:selectTest}"
                ],
                "presentation": {
                    "echo": false,
                    "reveal": "always",
                    "clear": false,
                    "showReuseMessage": false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```